# How to determine smoothness or roughness of contour OpenCv Python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to compare simple geometric images on a white background. These images should be labeled similar ([Ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI8pH.png) [Ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfODU.png) and [Ex1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sC2j2.png) [Ex2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLe6G.jpg)). Due to the nature of the objects, Feature Matching does not generate enough accurate matches to determine similarity and matchshapes does not take into account internal features. I would like to detect when the outer contour has additives on it that distort the shape when compared to the corresponding image. Is it possible to determine the smoothness / roughness of a contour using opencv?

Comment: Perhaps you can use the Freeman chain code from the contours to do contour matching. See https://compvis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contours.html. The circularity measure determines how it deviates from a circle. But that is just one number. See SimpleBlobDetector in OpenCV for its metrics. Also see https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d5/d72/classcv_1_1ximgproc_1_1ContourFitting.html#a5e4d25365e3033d2d8113a6e1a2c2db1 for contourFitting using Fourier Descriptors to compare two contours.

Comment: You question is a bit confusing. You say you want to consider internal features, but then you only want the outer contour. If you only consider the outer contour, then you might as well use shape matching based upon Hu Image moments. But perhaps the contourFitting might do better. I have not worked with that, yet.